# Regular Expression to get the IP after 2 DELETE from apache log

Tags: python, regex

I have sever.log file. My regular expression is extracting all the IP after 2 DELETE

```
192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] "DELETE /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0" 200 5042 "http://cooper.com/homepage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/5342 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.870.0 Safari/5342"
10.30.24.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] "DELETE /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0" 200 4939 "http://www.cole-brown.net/category/main/list/privacy/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/5322 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.843.0 Safari/5322"
98.5.45.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:49 +0000] "GET /apps/cart.jsp?appID=8471 HTTP/1.0" 200 4958 "http://knight-chase.com/post.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_7_3; rv:1.9.6.20) Gecko/2013-11-03 17:44:01 Firefox/3.8"
```

My Code is below

```
with open (r'C:\Users\ubuntu\Desktop\Tests\apache.log', 'r') as fr:
    lined = fr.read()
#print (line)
regex = r"DELETE.*?DELETE.*?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})"
print(re.findall(regex, lined,re.DOTALL))
```

My Output

```
['14.0.843.0']
```

Desired out

```
['98.5.45.3']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the IP on the same line as the second `DELETE` as it is the closest one. You need to get to the next line:

```
regex=r'DELETE.*?DELETE[^\n]*\n(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
print(re.findall(regex, lined, re.DOTALL))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZwdgRl/1).

The `[^\n]*\n` part will only match 0+ chars other than newline and then a newline.

Or, you may use and equivalent:

```
regex=r'DELETE[\s\S]*?DELETE.*\n(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
print(re.findall(regex, lined))
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZwdgRl/2). Here, `[\s\S]*?` will match any 0+ chars as few as possible (`.` can't be used as `re.DOTALL` is removed) and then `.*` will match any  0+ chars other than line break chars.

Comment: My output is None. I am reading from the file. Is it because of that?

Comment: @sim What do you mean? I see the code above. What code does not work? Please share an online demo using http://rextester.com  or http://ideone.com

Comment: regex = r"DELETE.*?DELETE.*?\s{1,}(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})", this regex also working. \s{1,} 
 Is it fine this regex also?

Comment: @sim Watch out, `\s{1,}` = `\s+` matches any 1 or more whitespaces, it does not guarantee to match *newline* chars only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/BafOig/1) regular expression. It's a bit complicated, cause it validates ip address *([if any of segments > 255 regex won't capture it](https://regex101.com/r/gXyARt/1))*.

```
import re

s = '''192.168.10.20 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:41:37 +0000] "DELETE /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0" 200 5042 "http://cooper.com/homepage/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/5342 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.870.0 Safari/5342"
10.30.24.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:15 +0000] "DELETE /search/tag/list HTTP/1.0" 200 4939 "http://www.cole-brown.net/category/main/list/privacy/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/5322 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/14.0.843.0 Safari/5322"
98.5.45.3 - - [18/Jul/2017:08:45:49 +0000] "GET /apps/cart.jsp?appID=8471 HTTP/1.0" 200 4958 "http://knight-chase.com/post.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; PPC Mac OS X 10_7_3; rv:1.9.6.20) Gecko/2013-11-03 17:44:01 Firefox/3.8"'''
expr = r"(?:.+DELETE.+[\r\n]+){2}^((?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\b"

result = re.search(expr, s, re.MULTILINE)  # you may use re.findall with same arguments set
print(result.group(1))  # first group contains ip address
```

Comment: My output is None. I am reading from the file. Is it because of that?

Comment: @sim, code works if you'll replace predefined value in s with `s = open("file.txt").read()`, so I don't understand where it can be broken to return `None`.